# Homogeneous function 3 variables

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I am trying to reduce a three-dimensional, homogenous function into a homogenous function of one argument.

$$f(x,y,z)=b^{-d}f(b^{h_x}x,b^{h_y}y,b^{h_z}z)$$

I decided to reduce one of the arguments first by choosing

$b^{h_x}=x^{-1}$

In which I succeed to reduce getting

$$f(x,y,z)=x^{\frac{d}{h_x}}f(t^{\frac{-h_y}{h_x}}y,y^{\frac{-h_{z}}{h_x}}z)$$

But I am not sure how to go from here, because if I apply the scaling again with the same constants I get unreasonable answer, should I use different scaling variables?